# Property 'get' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'

Tags: angular

Am very new to Angular js , Trying to learn it from youtube, and i was facing mentioned issue
 in my code, I don't understand what was missing in my code

## ERROR

**am getting " Property 'get' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'"**  error when am trying to access get service of HttpClientModule.,
 
Below are the code details
app.component.ts file is

```
import { Component,OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
   import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
     @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {

   constructor(private http:HttpClientModule){};
   title = 'app';
   ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/techsithgit/json-faker-
   directory/profiles').
    subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    });

   }

}
```

app.module.ts file is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "trust",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try importing HttpClient then :D 
`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to use `HttpClient` not `HttpClientModule` to make an http request.

In **app.module.ts**, import `HttpClientModule` (see "imports" below):

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
          HttpClientModule,
    ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then, import `HttpClient` in **app.component.ts**:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Now, change your AppComponent Ctor from

```
constructor(private http: HttpClientModule){};
```

to

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){};
```

Comment: I have tried the mention.. but i got error in console like.       
**" Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation"**

Comment: You need to "imports" `HttpClientModule` in your AppModule, and use `HttpClient` in your components. Sorry if my answer was unclear. Updated it.

Answer (score 14):

Beside you get this error if you did not pay attention on the imports for HTTPClient. Usually it defaults to

```
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
```

Comment: yes I also faced this issue. HttpClient had got imported from 'selenium-webdriver/http' instead of from '@angular/common/http'. Check your imports too

Answer (score 1):

Change/add those code/method from header and imports

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and in import section add this code:

```
 HttpClientModule,
```

indicated in the pic:

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYKoz.jpg)

Include those header in your class where you try to access httpClient :

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and for map use this code `.map(res => res );` instead of  `.map((res: Response) => res.json() );`

And from this pic you can see how to solve 'get' problem:

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz8Hh.jpg)

For get the clear concept watch pic1 and pic2.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component ({
  selector:'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  results;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todaydate = this.myservice.getTodayDate();
    this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
     this.results = data;
   });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your files like this, my environmental parameters:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.7
Node: 12.7.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.7
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.7
@schematics/angular          9.1.7
@schematics/update           0.901.7
rxjs                         6.5.4
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CribListingComponent } from './crib-listing/crib-listing.component';
import { CribCardComponent } from './crib-card/crib-card.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CribListingComponent,
    CribCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hello-world';
}
```

crib-listing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crib-listing',
  templateUrl: './crib-listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crib-listing.component.css']
})
export class CribListingComponent implements OnInit {

  cribs: Array<any>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // make an http request
    this.http.get('data/cribs.json')
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app.component.ts file , you have to inject "HttpClient" in your constructor, not "HttpClientModule".

1. your error come from here:
   [image]

change it to:

```js
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
```

2. and from here:
   [image]

change it to:

```js
constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }
```

NB: in app.module.ts we import "HttpClientModule" & in app.component.ts we inject "HttpClient"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32047599)

Comment: I think I gave the necessary explanations to correct the error